# GAE service running on Flexible Env. as target of a task queue

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, app-engine-flexible

According to the google doc, a service running in the flexible enviroment can be the target of a push task:

> Outside of the standard environment, you can't add tasks to push
>   queues, but a service running in the flexible environment can be the
>   target of a push task. You can specify this using the target parameter
>   when adding a task to queue or by specifying the default target for
>   the queue in queue.yaml.

However, when I tried to do it I get 404 errors in the flexible service.

That's totally normal due to the required endpoint (/_ah/queue/deferred) for task queues is it not defined in the flexible service.

How do I become a flexible service in a valid target for task queues?

Do I have to define that endpoint in my code in some way?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you'll need to [write a handler](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/taskqueue/push#working_with_push_queues) in your worker service to do the processing after receiving a task. In the case of push tasks, the service will send [HTTP requests](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/taskqueue/push/) to your whatever [url](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/taskqueue/push/creating-tasks#specifying_the_worker_service) you specify. If no url is specified the default URL /_ah/queue/[QUEUE_NAME] will be used.

Now, from the endpoint you mention, it seems you are using deferred tasks, which are a somewhat special kind. Please, see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33968512/failed-to-import-google-appengine-ext-deferred-handler-py-in-google-app-engine) for a workaround by adding the needed url entry. It mentions Managed VMS but it should still work.

Comment: That workaround is not valid for GAE services in Flexible environment for two reasons: 1- The "handler" directive is not allowed for flex env. 2- The script required (google.appengine.ext.deferred.application) is part of the GAE libraries which don't work on flex, it's exclusive for GAE standard (or old VMs, the one mentioned in the thread)

Comment: It seems that the only way to make it work is to define the endpoint in my own code (not in yaml ) and develop the proper source code in order to deal with the request from task queues (my own google.appengine.ext.deferred.application)

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear enough. Handler is an overloaded word. In this case,   writing a handler means writing whatever "your own code" is to deal with a matching url. The mapping between URL and handler depends on the framework you use. Regarding the deferred module not working on flex, you might be right as I have not tried myself but was relying on Alex's vast experience. See: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/google-appengine/Alex$20Martelli$20deferred|sort:relevance/google-appengine/GrprBiHGyns/Skb96WGPBwAJ